# awk insert server time at the beginning/end of line

Tags: awk

I need some help about printf.

Currently I have this script

```
awk '{c[$1"\t"$7]++}END{for(x in c)if (c[x]>10){printf "from %s (%d)\n",x,c[x]}}' /checkip.log >> bb.log
```

It gives me

```
from 120.230.xx.xxx /index (16)

from 120.231.xx.xxx /index (16)

from 120.236.xx.xxx /index (16)
```

and so on.

I would like to have my current linux server time (not date from `checkip.log`) printed at the beginning/end of each line.

For example

```
[07/Mar/2020:20:00:04 +0000] from 120.230.xx.xxx /index (16)

[07/Mar/2020:20:00:04 +0000] from 120.231.xx.xxx /index (16)

[07/Mar/2020:20:00:04 +0000] from 120.236.xx.xxx /index (16)
```

Comment: See `https://www.unix.com/unix-for-beginners-questions-and-answers/283900-awk-printf-help.html`

Comment: When you say `current linux server time` - do you mean the time you started running awk on your file or the time when awk reads an individual line from the file? They'll usually be the same value to the second but it depends how big your input is. Checking the time once when the script starts would obviously far more efficient than checking it once per line of input.

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU awk, then

```
awk 'BEGIN{ d=strftime("[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]") }
    {c[$1"\t"$7]++}
    END{for(x in c)if (c[x]>10){printf "%s from %s (%d)\n",d,x,c[x]}}' /checkip.log >> bb.log
```

If you don't have GNU awk then use

```
awk -vd="$(date '+[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]')" '{c[$1"\t"$7]++}
    END{for(x in c)if (c[x]>10){printf "%s from %s (%d)\n",d,x,c[x]}}' /checkip.log >> bb.log
```

to get date to calculate the string to be inserted.

Standard disclaimer, day monthname year hour minute second is a poor choice if you ever want to sort the results simply. Consider year month day hour minute second.